# json output from a url, test in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a URl like

http://abcd.com/xxx/1234.json
http://abcd.com/xxx/1235.json
This URL is accessed from third party site

i tried the script here https://gist.github.com/timsavery/1657351

but i am getting error when trying

```
1.9.3-p194 :025 > response = http.request(request)
=> #<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>
```

I am able to see the information in the browser by providing username, pwd, but i don know how do i test this in a rails console?
i want to save the json information to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the site is protected with some sort of authorization. In ruby, you can try setting basic authorization in the request headers like this:

`request.basic_auth 'username', 'secret'`

If that isn't the answer, then you need to look how the service requires you to authenticate the request.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using cURL. It's a UNIX command line function designed for this functionality. [Link here.](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)